# resource 150 of mysql result

Tags: php, mysql

What is resource(150) of type (mysql result)? I am getting that after var_dumping an select query,

My code is:

```
$userlevelcheck = $this->query_silent("SELECT user_level FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "users WHERE user_id='" . $user_id . "'"); 
var_dump ($userlevelcheck);
if ($userlevelcheck != "1")
{
    code
}
```

Comment: That's a result resource. You need to fetch rows from it.  `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($userlevelcheck)) {print_r($row);}`

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: It's the ID of the data-type `resource` in PHP. Analogous to Handles.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$userlevelquery = $this->query_silent("SELECT user_level FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "users     WHERE user_id='" . $user_id . "'"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
if ($row['user_level'] != "1")
{
    code
}
```

You need to get the row with the data in ($row) then check the relevant field $row['user_level']